# Audio file won't play using resourceUrl inside plugin

Tags: templating, resources

Essentially I'm moving a static HTML site into Craft. I've created a new plugin for the site and have gotten a good chunk of it working however I'm having an issue where audio files won't play.

The site is supposed to have music auto-playing and looping (it's a site for kids before you start judging me), and it works correctly on the static site, however nothing plays in my Craft instance and when I go to the direct URL for the audio file it won't play in browser either but doesn't give me a 404. If I "Save As" it does then download correctly.

Code is very simple:

```
<audio autoplay loop>
        <source src="{{ resourceUrl('somesite/audio/some_theme_full.ogg') }}" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="{{ resourceUrl('somesite/audio/some_theme_full.mp3') }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The src generates correctly as e.g http://site.local/cpresources/somesite/audio/some_theme_full.mp3?d=1513706441.

Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way to solve your issue is to create a new `Asset` for each of your audio files and relate it to your entries.

```
<audio autoplay loop>
    {% set audioFiles = entry.assetFieldHandle.all() %}
    {% for asset in audioFiles %}
        <source src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" type="{{ asset.getMimeType() }}">
    {% endif %}
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't want the assets to have to be uploaded and need them contained to the plugin. It also doesn't really solve my issue of why the audio files won't play.

Comment: Are you using Craft 3 or Craft 2?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using Craft 2. I'm stuck using this version due to my client.